# c++: использования ссылок и указателей в качестве параметров фунций

Tags: c++, функции, указатели, ссылки, параметры

Заинтересовал вопрос - а когда лучше использовать ссылки, а когда указатели в качестве параметров функций для объектов?

Например:

```
CMyData1 data1;
CMyData2 data2;

func_r(data1, data2);
func_p(&data1, &data2);
```

По идее - абсолютно без разницы, с ссылками чуть поудобнее, поскольку не приходится писать `->`, а используется родное для объектов `.`.

Можно ли сказать, что можно использовать такое правило:

если функция ожидает на вход только существующие объекты, тогда использоваться ссылки, если предполагается, что объект может не существовать, то тогда использовать надо указатели (чтобы можно было передать `nullptr`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- функция ожидает существующий объект без передачи владения - используется `T &`
- функция ожидает существующий объект без передачи владения или ничего - используется `optional<T &>`
- функция ожидает существующий объект c передачей владения или ничего - используется `smart_pointer<T>`
- функция ожидает кусок массива (строки) - используется `array_view<T>` или `string_view<T>`

Таким образом, использование сырых указателей ограничено реализациями этих `optional`, `smart_pointer`, `array_view` и т.п.

Comment: Умный указатель - это не обязательно передача владения, может быть и разделение - `shared_ptr`, или всего лишь попытка это сделать - `weak_ptr`.

Comment: спасибо, в мое время `optional` не было :) - по идее это сразу решает вопрос о возможности передать пустой объект

а что значит "передать владение"?

Comment: @Zhihar указатель типа [`std::unique_ptr`](https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) является владеющим, то есть при удалении (например, вызове деструктора) так же удаляет и объект, который привязан к этому указателю. Это базовая концепция "умных" указателей.